# Jquery: How to check/uncheck a list of checkbox's on checkbox click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to uncheck all the **Reject** checkbox's on clicking **Approve** checkbox header and vice versa. How can I achieve this using jquery/javascript.

[image: Here is an image depicting my requirement]

My HTML code is as follows

```
 <asp:TemplateField >
        <HeaderTemplate>
            Approve
            <br />
            <input id="ChkAllApprovedItems"  type="checkbox"  />
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkApproval" Checked='<%#Eval("IsApproved").ToString()=="1"?true:false %>'  runat="server" onclick="EnableApprove(this,this.checked);" />
         </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

     <asp:TemplateField >
        <HeaderTemplate>
            Reject
            <br />
            <input id="ChkAllRejectedItems"  type="checkbox"  />
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkReject" Checked='<%#Eval("IsRejected").ToString()=="1"?true:false %>'  runat="server"  onclick="EnableReject(this,this.checked);" />
         </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Can someone help me with a sample code.

Thanks.

Comment: If you include your HTML then it will be easier to provide sensible sample code.

Comment: @Jithin just a idea to get you started `$("input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)",context)` will give you unchecked checkboxes from inside context element(which might be a div tag on the page).

Comment: I would avoid using any :checked or :not(:checked) selectors because in this example, you don't need to select boxes that are in particular state. You just need to uncheck ALL boxes of a particular type (reject or approve).

Comment: I am dynamically generating the checkbox's in a grid.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pretty simple example:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZcFda/2/

- Get all all the accept and reject checkboxes into two arrays
- Bind "click" events to the two header checkboxes
- When a header is clicked, see if the click has caused it to be "checked"
- If so, cycle through the appropriate checkboxes and set checked = false

Comment: Thanks Doug. Can you please provide me with a sample code for my HTML

Comment: I don't really see much HTML up there — this looks like some proprietary XML tags that generate HTML. Instead, can you post the actual generated output, meaning, the HTML that appears when you "view source" on this page in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

You can change other check-box attribute based on main checkbox. [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cgQBn/1/)

```
$("#master_checkbox").change(function(){
    // if checkbox is checked then chek all
    if($(this).attr('checked')) {
        $(".change_me").attr('checked', 'checked');
    }
    // uncheck all
    else {
        $(".change_me").removeAttr('checked');    
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please provide me with a sample code for my HTML

Comment: Just change `$("#master_checkbox")` to `$("#ChkAllApprovedItems")` and add a class (`.change_me` or something else) to all checkboxes that you want to change in your html.